# Is there a way i can iterate over this list without repeating the same number?

Tags: python-3.x, igraph

i have this list i'm trying to iterate over to check if they are connected

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for ic in my_list:
    for i in ic:
        for j in ic:
             print(i,j)
```

my current loop gives me

```
output: 
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
.....
```

my desired output is

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
....
```

how can i make my loop go forward and skip `2 1` because i have `1 2`?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "check if they are connected". Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print` when `j >= i`:

```py
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for ic in my_list:
    for i in ic:
        for j in ic:
            if j >= i:
                print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you're hoping to do with each item in your list, but the `itertools` module might be what you're after:

```py
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> list(combinations_with_replacement([1,2,3], 2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: If additional computations are needed in the loop, one should go for the loop, but I don't feel that the loop would be more explicit, thus, this is the neat way to go about it. Consider also the `igraph` package which deals with graphs. This one-liner would combine an edge-list: `as_edgelist(make_full_graph(3, directed=F, loop=T))`, set `loop=F` to remove 1->1, and `directed=F` to include 2->1 as well as 1->2.